# Waiting until the player clicks a chess piece in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, wait, event-dispatch-thread

What is the proper way to implement the following code? I want to get the takeTurn() method to wait for the player to click on a button on the grid corresponding to the piece he wants to select. (`Button` objects have instance variables `int col, row` and `extend JButton`.)

```
int selectedCol, selectedRow;

void takeTurn() {
    System.out.print(name + "'s turn. ");

    // Get player to select a piece
    selectedCol = -1;
    selectedRow = -1;
    while (selectedCol == -1 && selectedRow == -1) {
        try {
            wait(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
    System.out.println(selectedCol + " " + selectedRow);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Button b = (Button)e.getSource();
    selectedCol = b.col;
    selectedRow = b.row;
}
```

Running gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: Do you mean `Thread.sleep(500)`? `wait()` is used with `notify()`/`notifyAll()` and it should be inside a synchronized block of code.

Comment: Thanks, Thread.sleep(500) is what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  @Eng.Fouad  I am surprised that you would add such questionable advice.  I have had cause to up-vote many of your answers, but if that were an answer, it would be -1.  :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why do you think `takeTurn()` is called from EDT? :P .. Besides I didn't notice this is a swing question :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  *"didn't notice this is a swing question"*  Well since it was only tagged as such *after* you made the comment, you are entirely forgiven.  :)  It was the hint of `JButton` that did it for me as I was editing the tags to add that & (based on 'swing') EDT.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

In Swing or AWT (or most UI frameworks), you should never block the main event thread.  This will cause your program to come to a halt and appear to have crashed or hung.

Instead you need to monitoring the state of the program based on the incoming events.

For example.

- Next users turn, rest internal variables
- Used clicked piece.  Maintain a reference to the piece
- Used click (some where).  If use has selected a piece, is the move valid? etc...

Answer (score 1):

A wait() only makes sense when there is also a notify(), so it's always about communication between threads, and that needs synchronization to work correctly. Your code seems to be missing the basic wait/notify model implementation.

There is a concept of Guarded block, which says

> Threads often have to coordinate their actions. The most common
>   coordination idiom is the guarded block. Such a block begins by
>   polling a condition that must be true before the block can proceed

Learn more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any `synchronization` in your code. Object  needs  to be in a `synchronized` context in order for `wait()` to work.

Create a `thread` and run your code  there and call `thread.wait()` there.